# Auto updated DOM trough chrome extension on duplicated tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a simple Chrome extension which toggles (show/hide) link in the particular web page.

It's a pretty simple structure with a switch input that turns the extension on/off.

Here's popup.js:

```
var $toggleSwitch = $("#myonoffswitch");

//Local storage state initialization
chrome.storage.sync.get(['sampleChecked'], function (result) {
$("#myonoffswitch").prop("checked", result.sampleChecked);
if (result.sampleChecked) {
  setOrangeIcon()
} else {
  setWhiteIcon()
}});

function toggleAllLinks() {
 chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  code: 'toggleLink()'
})}

function setOrangeIcon() {
 chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: 'icon1.png' })}

function setWhiteIcon() {
 chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: 'icon2.png' })}


$toggleSwitch.on("change", toggler);

function toggler() {
  $toggleSwitchChecked = $toggleSwitch.prop("checked");
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ "sampleChecked": $toggleSwitchChecked }, function () {
  console.log('Value is set to ' + $toggleSwitchChecked)});

toggleAllLinks();

if ($toggleSwitch.prop("checked")) {

   setOrangeIcon();

} else {

   setWhiteIcon();
}}
```

And my content.js

```
function showLinkCallback(event) {
 if (event.target.innerText) {
    if (event.target.innerText.indexOf("EIP") != -1) {
        var link = $("label:contains('EIP')~a")
        .after("<a>Demo Page</a>")
        .css({
            'display': "inline",
            'margin': "5px"
        });

        var endpoint = $("a:contains('Demo Page')")
        var r = /\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/;


        let authorIP = link[0].href;
        let dispatchIP =link[1].href;
        let publishIP = link[2].href;



        var trimAuthor = authorIP.match(r);
        var trimDispatch = dispatchIP.match(r);
        var trimPublish = publishIP.match(r);

        var authorEndpoint = $(endpoint)[0];
        var dispatchEndpoint = $(endpoint)[1];
        var publishEndpoint = $(endpoint)[2];
        $(authorEndpoint).attr('href', 'http://'+trimAuthor+':4502/content/hello-world.html');
        $(dispatchEndpoint).attr('href', 'http://'+trimDispatch+'/content/hello-world.html');
        $(publishEndpoint).attr('href', 'http://'+trimPublish+':4503/content/hello-world.html');

        toggleLink();
    }}}

document.querySelector(".content").addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', showLinkCallback);

 function toggleLink() {
   chrome.storage.sync.get(["sampleChecked"], function (result) {

    if (result.sampleChecked) {

        $("label:contains('EIP')~a~a").show();  
    } else {

        $("label:contains('EIP')~a~a").hide();
    }})};
```

SO my my problem is:

When I switch extension on/off, the link toggles (show/hide), and when i reload page it saves the state of the extension.
What I want is when I duplicate tab and toggle my button on/off that links in all duplicated tabs  show/hide simultaneously in real time, without rloading the page.

I suppose it has something with background.js file but I have problems with setting up the right script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are informing the page of the change through `executeScript` with no tab ID, which defaults to the current tab. I see several problems with that:

1. Your state is not per-tab, you have only one global on/off. However, only the current tab is notified of the change, meaning the actual state is not consistent.

   This is exactly the problem you describe, but unless you store state per tab while fixing it, it won't be limited to duplicated tabs - it will toggle for all tabs.

   I will assume, for simplicity, that it's what you want - not a toggle for some group of tabs, but for all of them at once.
2. Every time you run `executeScript`, it creates a new virtual javascript file to append to add to the content script context. This does leak resources unnecessarily.

Instead of using `executeScript`, you should have an event listener in the content script that you can notify of the change. Normally, you'd use [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), but it doesn't solve the "how to broadcast to all tabs" problem.

Specifically for changes to `storage`, you can register a listener to [`chrome.storage.onChanged`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#event-onChanged).

Upsides: you don't need to do anything special to message the content script, and you will react to changes that originate by remote sync. Downsides: it's broadcast to all pages of the extension, so if you really need non-per-tab state, it's too simple a solution.

You may want to parse the event details to check if exactly what you wanted changed, so that you don't need to run your code too often for unrelated changes. Right now it's not a concern since it's the only thing you store, but it's best to put effort in early.

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener((changes, area) => {
  if (area == "sync" && "sampleChecked" in changes) {
    // Note, at this point you already have the new value
    //  so you don't have to query storage again in toggleLink
    toggleLink(changes.sampleChecked.newValue);
  }
});

function toggleLink(sampleChecked) {
  if (sampleChecked) {
    /* logic */
  } else {
    /* more logic */
  }
}
```